# CSS Padding is working WITH :after selector - how to make it work on main element independently

Tags: wordpress, css, less

In a WordPress widget design, I added a shadow effect to the widget headers with an image using css `:after` selector like (I'm using LESS):

```
h3.widget-title{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16*@toRem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  //line-height: 1.5;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;

  &:after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: transparent url('images/widget-head-shade-1.png') no-repeat center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 31px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

With these I'm having a widget title effect like this:
[image: widget-head shadow design]

BUT, with the `padding-bottom: 5px;` it takes effect with the :after portion, taking the space with the shadow too. But I want to put the padding only on the bottom of the widget-title to make some space between the text and the shade:
[image]

The `padding-bottom` is taking space after the `:after` portion. You can check that [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzislam/eeZ3p/) - putting on and off the `padding-bottom` line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:after` and `:before` pseudo elements are children of the element they are added to ... and they get drawn after or before the content (inside your widget box). Adjusting the box model properties of the container will not affect the distance between the content and the pseudo element. So you need to add the margin/spacing to the pseudo element itself - to move it further away from the content.

Something like this, for example:

```
&:after {
  ...
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's a good explanation with the exact solution. Thanks a lot. +1